# How to compare a file in two different commits using the GUI

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I refer to https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/versioncontrol#_viewing-diffs.

Is there a way to easily show a side-by-side diff of a file in two different locations, eg work tree and a specific commit, using the Code GUI?

In Source Control view, if I click on a changed file, it shows a side-by-side diff of the work tree version and (I believe) the latest commit version. Is there a way to easily select another commit?

Comment: have you looked at the GitLens extension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coming to vscode (Insiders Build v1.54) is the ability to **compare a file from any two commits**.  It will operate using the context menu items `Select for Compare` and `Compare with Selected` opening a diff editor with the `Select for Compare` version on the left.

Previously, you could only compare any file version to the current version.  Now you could compare versions from any two commits.

[image: timeline compare]

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/116361#issuecomment-783524802

---

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_44.md#timeline-view for v1.44 info.

In v1.43 the Timeline view is available in the standard version via the same setting mentioned below.

> We've now added paging support (via *Load more* above), and added a
> relative timestamp over on the right. Extensions can also contribute
> menu items to the Timeline view as well as to individual timeline
> items. In the screenshot above, you can see that the built-in Git
> extension is contributing a few new commands: *Copy Commit ID* and *Copy
> Commit Message*.

[image: Timeline view]

---

The new  (v1.42) Timeline view does what you want. See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_42.md#timeline-view

> In this milestone, we've made progress on the new Timeline view, and
> have an early preview to share. This is a unified view for visualizing
> time-series events (for example, Git commits, file saves, test runs,
> etc.) for a resource (file, folder). To enable the Timeline view, you
> must be using the Insiders edition and then add the following setting:
>
> `"timeline.showView": true`  // has been removed

- use View/Open View... instead and look for `Timeline`

> Below you can see the Timeline view displaying the Git commit history
> of a file:

[image: Timeline demo]

> In this early preview, the Timeline view shows the Git commit history
> of the active document, which is currently limited to 32 items.
> Selecting one of those commits will open a diff view of the changes
> introduced by that commit. Extensions will also be able to contribute
> their own timeline sources, which will be shown in this unified
> timeline view. Eventually, you will also be able to select (filter),
> which sources you'd like to see in the view.
>
> Stay tuned, we have much more in store for this new feature. You can
> follow along by subscribing to issue #84297 and by watching for issues
> tagged with the 'timeline' label. And if you have ideas on other types
> of information you'd like to see in this view, let us know!

---

My demo: Your current file is always on the left - it doesn't look like you can alter that.  So it is always current file<->pick a commit diff.  Not compare two different commits to each other.

[image: timeline demo2]

Comment: I am now on 1.43.1 on the normal version, but still don't see Timeline or File/Open Timeline. Is it available yet?

Comment: Try right-clicking on the header bar of anything in your side bar - like "Outline" or the project name ("Experimental" in my gif) - there should be an "Outline" there you can enable.  There used to be a setting in the Insiders' Build which is now gone.  Let me know if that works and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Right clicking the project name shows Hide, Open Editors, Folders, Outline, NPM Scripts. My Outline is enabled. It shows the document outline of html and json files.

Comment: I also see it listed in the main menu "View/Open View..."

Comment: I can't find a match when I typed in `Time` if View/Open View. I am not sure if Timeline is available in 1.43.1 even though you mentioned it's available in 1.42. Must any plugin be installed first? Anyway, I am confused over the version numbering. I wonder how the link you posted in February was able to speak on the Mar 2020 release in the present tense.

Comment: I'm on v1.44.  "In v1.43 the Timeline view is available in the standard version via the same setting mentioned below." from my answer, so you need `"timeline.showView": true` in your settings.

Comment: Yes!  Need to set `timeline.showView` to true. Thanks.