# How do I see the contents of the file / files in visual studio code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

how do I see the history of a file/files in visual studio code in git ???
like I want to see the previous code of my previous commit ?
I've used `gitk` but I don't see the previous contents of the previous file that I've committed there.

I've already installed

> Git History Diff

&

> Gitlens

Answer (score 0):

There is also the new **Timelin**e feature built-in to vscode, see [How to compare a file in two different commits using the GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60098917/how-to-compare-a-file-in-two-different-commits-using-the-gui/60099757#60099757)

It will give you a diff between your current code and any commit that altered that code.

It is in preview now, so enable

> Timeline: Show View

in your settings.  I think it may be out of preview in v1.44 due this week.

[image: timeline]