# Is in Visual Studio Code a "compare with unmodified" option? (like in VS)

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, version-control, solution-explorer

In **Visual Studio *classic***, when you right-click a modified file under version control (Git) in Solution Explorer, it shows the following:

[image]

With the **useful** option "*Compare with unmodified*"

There is no such thing in Visual Studio Code's Solution Explorer, you have to go to the Source Control area:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve similar functionality in VS Code?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60099757/836330 in case you are not aware of the Timeline view and ability to compare git versions to the latest or between versions.

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I got a **Visual Studio Code PlugIn**:

[GitLens — Git supercharged](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens)

It has what I was looking for (and more):

[image: GitLens — Git supercharged]